# Azure Mobile Web Services with Table Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-mobile-services

I have added some data to Table storage via Azure Mobile Services.

I note that the rows do not include a PartitionKey or RowKey.  The row includes an ID.

Is Table Storage in Azure Mobile Services different than Azure Table Storage?

Thanks.

Thank you, Terrence

Answer (score 2):

Tables in Azure Mobile Services are Database tables stored in a SQL Azure Database.

- Azure Table Storage -> NoSql-type Data Store []
- Azure Mobile Services ->  SQL Database with Mobile Services Sync, full ACID, relationships, indexes etc.